# Algorithms -- eliminating a loop

Tags: algorithm

A universal sink in a directed graph is a vertex v where the in-degree of v is 
|V|-1 and out-degree is 0.

I can determine whether a directed graph G has a universal sink by the following alg.
Note: G is represented as an adjacency matrix AdjM and AdjM is given:

```
for (i=1 to |V|) 
   if (AdjM[i,1] + AdjM[i,2] + AdjM[i,3] + ... + AdjM[i,|V|] == 0) 
     && (AdjM[1,i] + AdjM[2,i] + AdjM[3,i] + ... + AdjM[|V|,i] == |V|-1) 
    then return i;  // i is a universal sink
```

I solved this problem in O(|V|) time by writing all 
|V| of AdjM[i,*] and AdjM[*,i] values in the code and thus eliminating an inner loop to do these summations.

Is there a way of doing this-- solving it in O(|V|) time without explicitly 
coding the summations with each AdjM[i,*] and AdjM[*,i] as the terms in the summations?

There must be a better way to do it using bit-wise operations, but I can't see it now.

This is Q 22.1-6 in section "Representations of Graphs" of CLRS, p.530.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily construct a graph with one universal sink, and change it to a graph with no universal sink by changing only one value in AdjM.  This means that you *must* examine every value in AdjM in order to determine if a universal sink exists.

No matter how cleverly you manipulate the indices and pointers, you cannot beat O(|V|^2).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in O(|V|) as shown [here](https://code.google.com/p/clrs/source/browse/ch22/22.1-6.py)

Answer (score -1):

Basically, you don't need the sum. You can just check that

- all `AdjM[i, _]` are 0
- all `AdjM[_, i]` are 1 except for `AdjM[i, i]`.

I don't however see how you can eliminate the loop. The solution with checks will be typically faster because you can break out of the loop as soon as any of the condition checks fails.

Comment: Looking to eliminate the inner loop. this isn't what it is about.

Comment: @Roam: you cannot, you need to access all the values in the row. Well, you can unroll in manually.